# comparing tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

So I have a list of tuples, for example:

```
[('CX8888', '2017-01-01T00:10:59'), ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:11:39'), ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:12:08')]
```

And if the first index of one tuple is the same as another it will make a new list like this:

```
[('CX8888', '2017-01-01T00:10:59'), ('RJ5874', ['2017-01-01T00:11:39', '2017-01-01T00:12:08'])]
```

Comment: This is similar to your previous question which you deleted. Can you please show us what you've tried to solve this first? That will turn the downvotes into upvotes. This isn't a code-for-free service.

Comment: The easiest way is to just iterate over them. I'm not a Python programmer, but in PHP I'd use `array_reduce`

Comment: Do you really want a list? the way its set up would suit a dictionary more

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionary instead of list then convert dictionary to desired format:

```
l = [('CX8888', '2017-01-01T00:10:59'), ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:11:39'), ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:12:08')]
d = {}
for tup in l:
    if tup[0] in d:
        d[tup[0]].append(tup[1])
    else:
        d[tup[0]] = [tup[1]]

list(zip(d.keys(),d.values()))
[('CX8888', ['2017-01-01T00:10:59']),
 ('RJ5874', ['2017-01-01T00:11:39', '2017-01-01T00:12:08'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way would be to use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?collections.defaultdict#collections.defaultdict) and then convert back to a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [('CX8888', '2017-01-01T00:10:59'), 
       ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:11:39'), ('RJ5874', '2017-01-01T00:12:08')]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in lst:
       d[key].append(value)
d2 = list(d.items())
```

but considering that data structure you might be better off just using the dictionary `d` instead of the list `d2`.